# $\max$ Operator on a Sum of Integrals

Tags: operator-theory

Define the value function

$$v(k) := \max_c\left[\int_0^t{F(s,c,k)ds}+\int_t^\infty{F(s,c,k)ds}\right]$$

Is this expression equal to
$$v(k) := \max_c\left[\int_0^t{F(s,c,k)ds}\right]+\max_c\left[\int_t^\infty{F(s,c,k)ds}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. It might be if the two partial maximums are achieved at the same value of $c$, but in general it will not be.